How to properly layout a level 4 IEC ESD / EFT / surge protection circuit for RS-485 busses?
I have made two pcb layouts, one very similar to texas instruments example circuits and one that is more space efficient. Which layout is the better one? Will the second one perform worse? If yes, why?



Neither will do much of anything without a ground. Is there a layer hidden--?

The return paths are important. If you do have an ESD event on XLR connector data pin, it will hit some protection device, but how it flows out from the protection device, through which path, is it earthed metal box or battery operates plastic cased device with no exposed metal parts? Also, from earlier questions, you are doing DMX512 and 3-pin XLR is not officially allowed connector. Instead of heavy protection, have you considered an isolated transmitter? Although the norm is that XLR GND pin is allowed to be earthed at transmitter.

@Justme the transmitter actually has internal protection and is isolated, but the datasheet suggest those measures to further increase its resilience. Texas Instruments ISO3086DWR. Now, the return path: I have it connected to ground of the isolated DC/DC converter. Is it a good return path? How should I ground everything when it's powered over usb? Also yes I know that 3 pin is not allowed but my venue needs it and I have to support it
